# How to catch a YUI3 Sortable drag event?

Tags: yui3

The drag-n-drop sort works great but I would like to know how to catch when someone does a drag.

I tried this but none of the alerts fire:

```
YUI().use('sortable', function(Y) {
var sortable1 = new Y.Sortable({
    container: '#demo1',
    nodes: 'li',
    on: {
        nodesChange: function() {
            alert('nodes');
        }
    },
    after: {
        containerChange: function() {
            alert('container');
        }
    },
    after: {
        moveTypeChange: function() {
            alert('moveType');
        }
    }
});
});
```

The above code just doesn't work at all.

In the code below, I've now gotten a `click` event to work but not the `copy` event.

```
YUI().use('event', 'node', function (Y) {
    var clickedNode = Y.one('#save-order-quicklink');

    var draggedNodes = Y.all('.results-row');
    if (draggedNodes) {
        draggedNodes.each( function(node) {
            node.on('click', function(eventFacade) {
                alert('click');
            });
            node.after('copy', function(eventFacade) {
                alert('copy');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The documentation for the `copy` event says:

> copy
>   copy ( event )
>   A Sortable node was moved.

Answer (score 0):

## How to listen for a YUI3 drag event:

To execute a callback when a YUI3 `Sortable` has been **dragged**, you can listen to `Sortable`'s [`moved`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Sortable.html#event_moved) event:

```
sortable.on('moved', function(event) {
    // your code here...
});
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `DragDropMgr` to listen to all `drag` events like so:

```
Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:drag', function(event) {
    // your code here...
});
```

Take a look at the [Drag and Drop User Guide](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/) for more information on [Drag and Drop `events`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/#events).

---

### Explanation for why your other code does not work:

#### Code Block 1:

The reason none of the events in your first code block fire is because they are listening for the [`nodes`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Sortable.html#attr_nodes), [`container`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Sortable.html#attr_container), and [`moveType`](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Sortable.html#attr_moveType) **attributes** to be changed. For example, code like `sortable1.set('nodes', newNodes);` would fire the `nodesChange` event.

See the YUI3 [`Sortable` User Guide](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/sortable/) for more details.

#### Code Block 2:

It's likely that your `copy` event listener does not fire in your second code block because you are not doing a `copy`, but I have no way of knowing this for sure.